# Cannot generate SSPI context from SQL Server Management Studio (2005)

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2005

Yesterday I went through some troubles to set up a DB on my local machine. I finally got that working, but now today I am getting an error when I try to connect to a remote machine.

```
Cannot generate SSPI context. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Server Name: remotedbserver
Error Number: 0
Severity: 11
State: 0
Procedure: GenClientContext
```

I tried rebooting, stopping all my local services, etc. Nothing seems to be working. I also tried to follow the steps to troubleshoot this found in the Microsoft Knowledge Database - nothing worked so far! I am using Windows 7 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally got a logon to the actual server. I think the problem was that someone had the service running under their account, and must have changed their password. Hope this helps if anyone else gets this message.